# SQL: Average of counts

Tags: sql, count, hive, average

In my Hive table, I have the following columns:

```
date, SessionID, url,              time_spent
20160901 119     www.hello.com/hehe  10
20160901 121     www.abc.com/xyz     5
20160901 119     www.google.com      12
```

I need to find the number of urls per sessionid for all dates.
I tried something on the lines of

```
Select sessionid, count(url), sum(time_spent) from my_table where date between '20160901' and '20160905' group by sessionid
```

... which does work for a tiny timeframe but there are millions of sessionid's per day and I need to get a year's worth of data, so this approach wouldn't work.

I figured an average representation of counts would work so I tried this:

```
select count(sessionid), average(count(url)), avg(sum(time_spent)) from my_table where date between '20160901' and '20160905' group by sessionid;
```

But this fails with

> Not yet supported place for UDAF 'count'

Is there a way to get the average of counts here?

Answer (score 0):

your sql error. you should use sql:

```
select sessionid, count(sessionid), average(count(url)), avg(sum(time_spent)) from my_table where date between '20160901' and '20160905' group by sessionid;
```

Comment: Right, but this would give me the average count of URLs and time spent for each sessionID. I have millions of sessionIDs in a day and potentially billions in a year so I'm looking to get the average of count(url) and sum(time(spent))  for the _whole_ table for that date range.

Comment: @Craig, To hive, increasing millons records day by day isn't a large number, I think. maybe, you need to add new machines to your hadoop cluster. If you want to get whole table's url number. you can use : `select count(distinct url), sum(time_spent), avg(time_spent) from my_table`

Comment: @aaronshon I understand. I did a row count and it's around 74 billion for the year. I decided to take random samples instead